# Type inference creating undesired constraint

Tags: f#, type-inference

Since I have a ton of `IDisposable`s that I need to take care of a while down the line, I set up a list of disposables and a pass-through function to add items to it as a side effect:

```
let mutable disposables = []
let (~-) (x:'a) = disposables <- x :: disposables; x
```

So that I could hopefully do this:

```
let thing1 = -new Form()
let thing2 = -new Control()

for i in disposables do i.Dispose()
```

The problem is that F# automatically constrains `'a` to `IDisposable`, with the warning message:

> This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations. The type variable 'a has been constrained to be type 'IDisposable'.

So then the return type of `operator ~-` becomes IDisposable, which defeats the convenience of the function.

Is there a way to prevent F# from creating this constraint?

Comment: If `disposables` is a list of `IDisposable`, then what can `x` be but an `IDisposable` itself? In any case, you might give `disposables` an explicit type and see what you get—I’m a Haskeller, so this is just conjecture.

Comment: Does doing `let inline (~-) (x:'a) = disposables <- x :: disposables; x` fix this?

Comment: @JohnPalmer Nope, `Local class bindings cannot be marked inline. Consider lifting the definition out of the class or else do not mark it as inline`.

Comment: @JonPurdy I need the returned `x` to be the type that I sent in, not `IDisposable`. Annotating a type on `disposables` doesn't seem to change much :(

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka - This error message implies that the entire code is encased within `type ... = ...` which explains why your example doesn't compile on its own

Comment: @ReiMiyasaka - had you considered using `using` instead of `let` - then the runtime will take care of getting rid of `IDisposables` for you

Comment: There are _much_ better ways of doing this!

Comment: @JohnPalmer As I explained in Daniel's answer, I can't be completely idiomatic, because I'm trying to avoid invoking the GC too much -- and that means I have to use classes in a lot of situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

The answer is to upcast `x` to `IDisposable` when I use it in the function, not in the function's type signature:

```
let mutable disposables = []
let (~-) x = disposables <- (x :> IDisposable) :: disposables; x
```

Comment: `(upcast x)` reads a bit better than `(x :> IDisposable)` IMO, but you'll need to give `disposables` an explicit type.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't ask for general advice about your code, but I feel obliged to point out a few oddities.

Firstly, you should almost never have to call `Dispose()`. `use` is the standard way of managing resources. You should probably be doing this:

```ml
use thing1 = new Form()
use thing2 = new Control()
```

Secondly, why would you assign an immutable data structure to a `mutable` variable? If you're convinced you need to manually track resources, use

```
let disposables = ResizeArray<IDisposable>()
```

Finally, you should think long and hard before defining an operator that mutates a variable outside its own scope. That is unusual behavior for an operator (unless the operator's scope is very narrow).

Comment: As much as I'd like to use `use`, I'm working on game code, so inevitably I have to work with the .NET Framework's native idioms in order to be efficient, especially in order to avoid invoking the GC too much. I use classes quite often because closures allocate on the heap each call. As far as using a list goes, I don't mind the overhead too much because the disposables are mostly huge resources that I won't be creating many of anyway -- so there isn't any practical difference between lists and ResizeArray.